# What does "special compiler magic" mean?

Tags: nim-lang

In the [Nim system module](http://devdocs.io/nim/system) it says:

> Most of the routines listed here use special compiler magic.

What do they mean by "special compiler magic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it means that the implementations of the routines in that module cannot be expressed in the source language itself. I.e. the compiler recognizes a special set of names and either uses special semantics or compiles in hand-written assembly, etc. The notice is usually to prevent someone from trying to reason about how the interface could be written in the language itself.